# Wrapping jQuery in a new, dynamically created Div

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function

Trying to get dynamically generated tooltips to be created within a grid. Currently they are appended to the body and I have to start by getting them in a wrapper, so I can define `display:grid`;

This is the code snippet and its appended to the body right after this. I have tried concatenating the wrapper div, but as `$tooltip` is called later, the functions try to run on the newly created div. I also tried `.wrap` & `.wrapAll` but didn't have any luck.

```
r.$tooltip = e(
   '<div id="' +
   r.options.ult_adv_id +
   '" class="ult-tooltipster-base ' +
   r.options.theme +
   '" style="' +
   BaseStyle +
   '"><div class="ult-tooltipster-content ult-responsive" data-ultimate-target="' +
   r.options.ultimate_target +
   '" data-responsive-json-new = \'' +
   r.options.responsive_json_new +
  '\' style="' +
  contentStyle +
  '"></div></div>'
);
```

Output:

```
<body>
  <div id="hotspot-tooltip-hs-three" class="ult-tooltipster-base ult-tooltipster-default">
    ##########
  </div>
</body>
```

Trying to achieve:

```
<body>
  <div id="hotspot-grid">
    <div id="hotspot-tooltip-hs-three" class="ult-tooltipster-base ult-tooltipster-default">
      ##########
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried concatenating the new div:

```
r.$tooltip = e(
   '<div id="hotspot-grid"><div id="' +
   r.options.ult_adv_id +
   '" class="ult-tooltipster-base ' +
   r.options.theme +
   '" style="' +
   BaseStyle +
   '"><div class="ult-tooltipster-content ult-responsive" data-ultimate-target="' +
   r.options.ultimate_target +
   '" data-responsive-json-new = \'' +
   r.options.responsive_json_new +
  '\' style="' +
  contentStyle +
  '"></div></div></div>'
);
```

Which worked for display purposes and the `div` is where I wanted if but as the newly created div is included in the variable for `$tooltip`, other functions later in the script are running using this and not the child div (which was of course previously the parent).

Then I tried `.wrap` & `.wrapAll` :

```
r.$tooltip = e(
   '<div id="' +
   r.options.ult_adv_id +
   '" class="ult-tooltipster-base ' +
   r.options.theme +
   '" style="' +
   BaseStyle +
   '"><div class="ult-tooltipster-content ult-responsive" data-ultimate-target="' +
   r.options.ultimate_target +
   '" data-responsive-json-new = \'' +
   r.options.responsive_json_new +
  '\' style="' +
  contentStyle +
  '"></div></div>'
).wrapAll( document.createElement( "div" ) );
```

then I tried .wrap & wrapAll further on down (before `r.$tooltip.appendTo('body');` )

```
r.$tooltip = e(
  '<div id="' +
  r.options.ult_adv_id +
  '" class="ult-tooltipster-base ' +
  r.options.theme +
  '" style="' +
  BaseStyle +
  '"><div class="ult-tooltipster-content ult-responsive" data-ultimate-target="' +
  r.options.ultimate_target +
  '" data-responsive-json-new = \'' +
  r.options.responsive_json_new +
  '\' style="' +
  contentStyle +
  '"></div></div>'
 );
                        
  if (l()) r.$tooltip.addClass(o);
  r._content_insert();
  ( 'ult-tooltipster-base' ).wrap("<div class='hotspot-grid'></div>");
  r.$tooltip.appendTo('body');
```

And of course none of these worked. I also created the new div on the page in HTML so it would exist,and tried to change `r.$tooltip.appendTo('body');` to `r.$tooltip.appendTo('body');` but also, No Bueno.